# Confidence interval of the sum of beta coefficient

Tags: r, confidence-interval, glmm

I'm currently trying to estiamates the evolution of runner speed in function of distance and sexe. I'm building a GLMM Gamma Model. For thoses using R, here is my model.

```
 Family: Gamma  ( log )
Formula:          speed ~ distance * sex + (1 | id)
Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 40269.0  40313.0 -20128.5  40257.0    11276 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id               (Intercept) 0.04165  0.2041  
Number of obs: 11282, groups:  id        , 4985

Dispersion estimate for Gamma family (sigma^2): 0.025 

Conditional model:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      2.0220311  0.0067005  301.77  < 2e-16 ***
distance        -0.0029798  0.0001023  -29.12  < 2e-16 ***
sexM             0.0286679  0.0095538    3.00  0.00269 ** 
distance:sexM   -0.0004437  0.0001442   -3.08  0.00210 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Basically this shape :  $$log(y) = a + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_1x_2 + random + \epsilon $$

Where $x_1$ is distance and is a continous variable and $x_2$ is sex with 0 = female and 1 = male.

I calculated the confidence interval :

```
                                                  2.5 %        97.5 %      Estimate
a = cond.(Intercept)                           2.0088983263  2.0351639254  2.0220311259
b1 = cond.distance                             -0.0031803055 -0.0027792483 -0.0029797769
b2 = cond.sexM                                  0.0099427175  0.0473930836  0.0286679005
b3 = cond.distance:sexM                        -0.0007263435 -0.0001609916 -0.0004436675
id.cond.Std.Dev.(Intercept)                0.1989180350  0.2093651910  0.2040747716
```

I would like to explain my results so I build two equations one for female and one for male :

$$
speed_F = exp(a + b_1 * x_1)
$$

$$
speed_M = exp(a + b_2 +  (b_1 + b_3 )* x_1)
$$

So here is my question: How can I calculated the confidence interval for $a + b_2$ and $b_1 + b_3$. Can I add the individual upper and lower bond ?

Thank you

Comment: I would say the way to go here would be to consider the coefficients of interest (say `b1` and `b3`) first as a 2-dim vector, compute their confidence region (an ellipse) at the desired confidence level (say 95%) using their estimated covariance matrix (2x2 matrix) and finally find the minimum and maximum values of `b1 + b3` falling *inside* this confidence region. Those minimum and maximum value would give you the 95% confidence interval for `b1 + b3`.